# Three.js normals update on object rotation

Tags: object, rotation, three.js, mesh, normals

I use a 3D object as a container for a few meshes. I am using an Orthographic camera. I vertically rotate the container by 90° like this:

```
        meshContainer.rotation.x = 0;
        meshContainer.rotation.y = - 90 * Math.PI / 180;
        meshContainer.rotation.z = 0;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

I have to do operations on the meshes inside the container depending on their orientation relative to the camera. So, i do this test:

```
            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
            vector.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);

            if (vector.dot(geom.faces[i].normal) < 0) { ... }
```

goem is the geometry of one mesh inside the container.

I just want to check if each face is 'looking at' the camera or not. It works fine when I rotate the container with mouse controls but not with a rotation as above. When I look at the mesh geometries, it seems that the normals of the faces are not udpated when I do the container rotation.

I tried this :

```
        mesh[value].geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        mesh[value].geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

on each mesh after the container rotation, but with no results.

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera position must be changed but not the mesh container and everything is fine